# find the end point of a pattern in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

There is a comma separated string in a column which looks like

```
test=1,value=2.2,system=321
```

I want to extract value out from the string. I can use `select PatIndex('%value=%',columnName)` then use left, but this only find the beginning of the patindex.

How to identify the end of pattern value=%, so we can extract the value out?

Comment: SQL, the language, isn't meant for string manipulation. Data shouldn't be stored like this in the first place. This breaks even the 1st Normal Form. It's *far* easier to split strings or handle CSV files when loading data

Comment: Those values should probably be separate columns in the table or a related, separate table. If you wanted to treat this string a a value you could have stored it as XML or JSON and use the XML or JSON functions. If you want to *query* them though, it means they can't be treated as simple values

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you targeting? SQL Server 2016 added [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and JSON support. XML was added back in 2005. You could have stored this string in an xml-typed field

Answer (score 2):

Chain a few `SUBSTRING` with `CHARINDEX` and your `PATHINDEX`.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'test=1,value=2.21954,system=321'

SELECT
    Original = @text,
    Parsed = SUBSTRING(                                     -- Get a portion of the original value
                @text,
                PATINDEX('%value=%',@text) + 6,             -- ... starting from the 'value=' (without the 'value=')
                -1 + CHARINDEX(                             -- ... and get as many characters until the first comma
                    ',',
                    SUBSTRING(                              -- ... (find the comma starting from the 'value=' onwards)
                        @text,
                        PATINDEX('%value=%',@text) + 6,
                        100)))
```

Result:

```
Original                        Parsed
test=1,value=2.2,system=321     2.2
```

Note that the `CHARINDEX` will fail if there is no comma after your `value=`. You can filter this with a `WHERE`.

I strongly suggest to store your values already split on a proper table and you wont have to deal with string nightmares like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CHARINDEX` with starting position to find the first comma *after* the pattern. `CROSS APPLY` is used to keep the query easier to read:

```
WITH tests(str) AS (
    SELECT 'test=1,value=2.2,system=321'
)
SELECT str, substring(str, pos1, pos2 - pos1) AS match
FROM tests
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PATINDEX('%value=%', str) + 6) AS ca1(pos1)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', str, pos1 + 1)) AS ca2(pos2)
-- 2.2
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *don't* store denormalized data in this way, if you want to query them. SQL, the language, isn't good at string manipulation. Parsing and splitting strings can't take advantage of indexes either, which means any query that tried to find eg all records that refer to `system 321` would have to scan and parse *all* rows.

**SQL Server 2016 and JSON**

SQL Server 2016 added suppor for JSON and the `STRING_SPLIT` function. Earlier versions already provided the XML type. It's better to store complex values as JSON or XML instead of trying to parse the string.

One option is to convert the string into a JSON object and retrieve the `value` contents, eg :

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'test=1,value=2.2,system=321'

select json_value('{"' + replace(replace(@text,',','","'),'=','":"') + '"}','$.value')
```

This returns `2.2`.

The replacements converted the original string into

```
{"test":"1","value":"2.2","system":"321"}
```

`JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.')` will return the `value` property of that object

**Earlier SQL Server versions**

In earlier SQL Server version, you can convert that string into an XML element the same way and use XQuery :

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = 'test=1,value=2.2,system=321';

declare @xml varchar(100)='<r ' + replace(replace(@text,',','" '),'=',' ="') + '" />';
select @xml
select cast(@xml as xml).value('(/r[1]/@value)','varchar(20)')
```

In this case `@xml` contains :

```
<r test ="1" value ="2.2" system ="321" />
```

The query result is `2.2`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML 
SELECT @xml = Cast(( '<X>' + Replace(txt, ',', '</X><X>') + '</X>' ) AS XML) 
FROM   (VALUES ('test=1,value=2.2,system=321')) v(txt) 

SELECT LEFT(value, Charindex('=', value) - 1)           AS LeftPart, 
       RIGHT(value, Charindex('=', Reverse(value)) - 1) AS RightPart 
FROM   (SELECT n.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS value 
        FROM   @xml.nodes('X') AS T(n))T
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/HGKL65127)

**Output**

```
+----------+-----------+
| LeftPart | RightPart |
+----------+-----------+
| test     | 1         |
+----------+-----------+
| value    | 2.2       |
+----------+-----------+
| system   | 321       |
+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query if you are using SQL Server (2016 or above)

```
SELECT RIGHT(Value,CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE(Value))-1) FROM YourTableName
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT ( ColumnName , ',' )  
WHERE Value Like 'Value=%'
```